# MPIO alike multipathing tool for Windows Server

Tags: storage, multipath, mpio

We are looking for free multipath tool available for Windows Servers alike MPIO. Vendor specific multipath tool like Powerpath for EMC are license based and would like to evaluate different open options available from independent vendors.

Comment: Note to shop-closers: There is one built right into the OS.

Answer (score 2):

There is one built into the operating system as of Windows Server 2008. It's an installable 'Feature'.

1. Go to Server Manager
2. Go to Features
3. Add a feature
4. Select `Multipath I/O`
5. Finish the install.
6. Reboot

Depending on what you're using for storage, you may or may not need a Device Specific Module for your hardware. Those can be obtained on the vendor websites.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm looking for any free multipath tools beside MPIO for Windows. Are there any opensource multipath tool available for Windows? There are multiple available for Unix/Linux version but i'm looking it for Windows OS.

Comment: You are asking for the DSM component, and the answer is no there are no open source DSM's for windows. All the vendor DSM's use MS MPIO stack to optimze things.